# TypeScript returns an array (map) index error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
type SubOptionType = {
  year: number
  zest: number
}

type OptionType = Partial<SubOptionType> & {
  id: number
  label: string
}

const optionList = useMemo(() => {
    return option.map((opt) => Object.keys(opt).filter((keyVal) => !removeItems.includes(keyVal)))
  }, [option])


<Autocomplete   
      renderTags={(tagValue) =>
        tagValue.map((tag: OptionType, index) => (
          <LabelChips key={tag.id} size="small" text={tag.label} >
            {optionList[index].map((el) => tag[el])}
          </LabelChips>
        ))
      }
/>
```

```
const option = [
    { id: 1, label: 'Casablanca', zest: 3000, year: 1950 },
    { id: 2, label: 'Psycho', zest: 3000, year: 1950 },
    { id: 3, label: 'The Green Mile', zest: 3000, year: 1950 },
    { id: 4, label: 'The Intouchables', zest: 3000, year: 1950 },
]

const optionList =
[
    [
        "zest",
        "year"
    ],
    [
        "zest",
        "year"
    ],   
]

tagValue.map(tag) => tag = { 
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Casablanca",
    "zest": 3000,
    "year": 1950
}
```

Error part:

`{optionList[index].map((el) => tag[el])}` <== error point!

Error name:

> In the Option Type an index signature containing parameters of the type could not be found.

How to index signature?

I wish to solve this using TypeScript.

Comment: What is `optionList`, `option`, and `tag` declaration? that is not a valid typescript code..

Comment: edit in question !!

Comment: `option Data` is still an invalid declaration. Are you exporting it from other file or its in the same file and you need to declare it using `let` or `const`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: nono its typescript error/
array problem is not

Comment: add option data declare !

Comment: What is this `tagValue.map(tag) => tag = { ` this is an arrow function with map?? Its invalid. Is this a secret language like meta hack before published :).

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve here @김찬영? Are you trying to show some sort of filters as chips on the `Autocomplete` component?

Comment: nono 
 renderTags={(tagValue) =>
        tagValue.map((tag: OptionType, index) => (
          <LabelChips key={tag.id} size="small" text={tag.label} >
            {optionList[index].map((el) => tag[el])}
          </LabelChips>
        ))
      }
tagvaule mappin in tag data!!

Comment: {optionList[index].map((el) => tag[el])}
=> indexing typescript error !!

Comment: Where is the declaration of tagValue?

Comment: Consider adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Reproduce it in typescript playground. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play.

Comment: description not good sorry im korean / english little ..
it is solved
everybody is thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the TypeScript error related to indexing signature, add the following index signature to the OptionType type:

```
type OptionType = Partial<SubOptionType> & {
  id: number
  label: string
  [key: string]: number | string | undefined
}
```